Add names to Workspace panel
On sles12 (with KDE)  I had names of workspaces on the workspace panel in mode "miniature view".
After IT updated to sles15 and XFCE, I don't have an option to add names to the panel.
KDE sles12
enter image description here
XFCE sles15
enter image description here
How can I add names to the panel ?
